# How to generate barcode in python as response of image object

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, barcode

Views.py:

```
def Bar(request):
    payload = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))
    a=payload["donor_n_key"]
    ean = barcode.get('code128', a, writer=ImageWriter())
    filename = ean.save('ean13')
    image = ean.render()
    return HttpResponse(image,content_type="image/png")
```

Here i have downloaded the barcode image but I am unable to open that image.I am getting the error is windows photo viewer can't open this picture because either photo viewer does not support this file format.

I am new to this django restframework.Please help me Anyone.

Answer (score 1):

In Your **View.py**

Import This

```
import barcode
from barcode.writer import ImageWriter


def Bar(request): 
    lineCode = '1234567891234'
    barCodeImage = barcode.get('ean13', lineCode, writer=ImageWriter())
    filename = barCodeImage.save(item_name.png)
    return HttpResponse(image,content_type="image/png")
```

It Will Generates Image and save it your project root folder

More help visit this link [PyBarcode](https://pythonhosted.org/pyBarcode/barcode.html#creating-barcodes-as-svg)